# Homebrew Corrupts PATH Variable on OSX Maverick

Tags: shell, homebrew, osx-mavericks, oh-my-zsh

A failed attempt to install a Homebrew package on a Maverick OSX Macbook Pro was terminated by a Cntrl-C process break. Afterwards, the ZSH shell profile is corrupted such that :

> uname
>   zsh: command not found: uname
>
> man
>   zsh: command not found: man
>
> ps
>   zsh: command not found: ps
>
> cat
>   zsh: command not found: cat
>
> echo $PATH
>   /usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:PATH:/usr/local/opt/curl/bin

/Users/..../.rvm/scripts/rvm:12: command not found: uname
/Users/.../.rvm/scripts/rvm:15: command not found: ps

> npm --version
>   5.5.1
>   parse_git_dirty:11: command not found: tail

Answer (score 0):

add /usr/bin to your PATH first

```
export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH
```